# Remove Duplicated Language Array

Tags: php, duplicates

I have a stupid question . I have 2 arrays :

```
$lang = array
(

'reglinkname_default'   => 'Register',//'注册',
'yes'           => 'Yes',//'是',
'no'            => 'No',//'否',
'index'         => 'Site Home',//'站点首页',
'setindex'      => 'Home',//'首页',
'submit'        => 'Submit',//'提交',
'submit_tips'       => 'Press Enter to submit your changes at any time',//'按 Enter 键可随时提交您的修改',
'reset'         => 'Reset',//'重置',
'ok'            => 'OK',//'确定',
'cancel'        => 'Cancel',//'取消',
'modify'        => 'Modify',//'修改',
'start'         => 'Start',//'开始',
'tips'          => 'Tips',//'技巧提示',
'tips_all'      => 'All tips',//'显示全部提示',

);

$lang2 = array
(

'subscribe_comsenz_email' => '填写您的邮件地址，订阅 Discuz! 官方产品动态、安全提醒、官方新闻',
'reglinkname_default' => '注册',
'yes' => '是',
'no' => '否',
'index' => '站点首页',
'setindex' => '首页',
'allthread' => '全部版块和群组',
'submit' => '提交',
'submit_tips' => '按 Enter 键可随时提交你的修改',
'reset' => '重置',
'ok' => '确定',
'cancel' => '取消',
'modify' => '修改',
'start' => '开始',
'tips' => '技巧提示',
'setseotips' => 'SEO优化设置提示',
'tips_all' => '显示全部提示',
'tips_textarea' => '双击输入框可扩大/缩小',
'name' => '名称',
'none' => '无',
'default' => '默认',
'use_default' => '- 使用默认 -',
'unknown' => '未知',
'unlimited' => '无限制',
'config' => '设置',
'admin' => '管理',
'add' => '添加',
);
```

I want to write a function to remove duplicated value and output the new value. I trued to use `array_unique()`, but  not success, and I want to print the value  with '' . Maybe you can help me , thanks so much.

Comment: Can you include the code where you tried `array_unique`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array_diff_assoc() (http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) to find the differences, then array_subtract to remove them.

Alternatively, if your goal is just to get an array with the things from lang1 if they exist, and from lang2 if they don't use `array_merge()`. Order matters so you'd want `array_merge($lang2, $lang1);` so lang1 takes precedence.

Comment: Well , solucky, i try and have it. Thanks you so much
$lang3 = array_merge($lang, $lang2);
$result = array_diff($lang3, $lang2);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);